# Suppressing C++ 'Post-Build Event' when using msbuild

Tags: c++, msbuild

I am using msbuild to build a C++ project and I want to suppress the 'Post-Build Event'.  I have tried the following properties with no success:

```
/property:PostBuildEvent=
/property:VCPostBuildEventTool=
```

Neither will make any difference and the post build events are still executed.

Does anyone know how to suppress these (and potentially other) events using msbuild?

Comment: Is this a C++ specific issue since I've found that doing /p:PostBuildEvent= suppresses the post build event fine for a c# project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out how to do this.  There's 2 steps involved:

First, if you're not starting the msbuild process using a batch file already, create a batch file that calls the msbuild process.  Then add a variable in the batch file before you call the msbuild process.  Something like this:

```
set ISFULLBUILD=True
msbuild TFSBuild.proj >> BuildOutput.txt
```

Then, you need to modify your post build event to only do something if the variable is not set, or has the wrong value:

```
IF NOT '%ISFULLBUILD%'=='True' copy /y $(TargetFileName) "..\..\..\..\..\..\Binaries\$(ConfigurationName)\"
```

In this case - the TargetFileName (Whatever.dll) will only get copied when you're building from Visual Studio.  But, when you build using your new batch file - it will NOT execute the command after the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the build event to something other than blank?  If you overwrite it with something superfluous, like a "dir" or something, does it still execute the original post-build steps?

It's not the most elegant solution, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Ack, it looks like msbuild actually calls vcbuild which isn't as flexible, so I think I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the post-build events, you could do this with an environment variable, say `SKIP_POST_BUILD_EVENTS`. You can then set that environment variable before calling `msbuild`, and check whether the variable exists in the post-build event before executing whatever code is there.